# Compiler won't recognize typedef in switch statement

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4

I've just started to learn objective c and I was playing around with typedef, enumerations, switch statements, and functions, just to become more familiar with them. From my understanding, this code should all work, but I get a compile error on where I declare the switch statement that says "unexpected type name 'dinnerPreference': expected expression. If I used typedef to define dinnerPreference, then why does this happen.

```
typedef  enum { pizza = 0, steak = 1, seafood = 2} dinnerPreference;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {


    dinnerPreference momDinnPref = pizza;
    dinnerPreference myDinnPref  = steak;
    dinnerPreference urDinnPref  = seafood;

    int dinnerPrefFunc ( dinnerPreference x ); {
        NSLog(@"Lets see what this guy wants for dinner");
        dinnerPreference x
        switch( dinnerPreference x ) {
            case pizza:
                NSLog(@"This person wants pizza");
                break;
            case steak:
                NSLog(@"This person wants steak");
                break;
            case seafood:
                NSLog(@"This person wants steak");
                break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"I dunno");
                break;
                return 0;
        };
    }
    dinnerPrefFunc(momDinnPref);
    dinnerPrefFunc(myDinnPref);
    dinnerPrefFunc(urDinnPref);
}
return 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective-C (and C, C++) do not support declaring functions *within* other functions, at least not in the way you have tried. Try re-ordering your code as follows:

```
typedef enum { pizza = 0, steak = 1, seafood = 2 } dinnerPreference;

int dinnerPrefFunc ( dinnerPreference x );
int dinnerPrefFunc ( dinnerPreference x )
{
    NSLog(@"Lets see what this guy wants for dinner");
    switch( x )
    {
        case pizza:
            NSLog(@"This person wants pizza");
            break;
        case steak:
            NSLog(@"This person wants steak");
            break;
        case seafood:
            NSLog(@"This person wants steak");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"I dunno");
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

   @autoreleasepool
   {

      dinnerPreference momDinnPref = pizza;
      dinnerPreference myDinnPref  = steak;
      dinnerPreference urDinnPref  = seafood;

      dinnerPrefFunc(momDinnPref);
      dinnerPrefFunc(myDinnPref);
      dinnerPrefFunc(urDinnPref);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
switch( dinnerPreference x ) {
```

Change it to:

```
switch (x) {
```

And also notice that, you have not initialized x yet.

Comment: @MowelBovement, http://infinite-josiah.blogspot.com/2012/12/why-you-should-try.html